# How do teams progress to the 2nd stage in case of same points?

Tags: rules, football, world-cup, tie-breaker

I am not very familiar with football. I only follow football matches during world cups. Suppose two teams end up the first group with same points then how the final group standing is decided? I can see Wins, Draws, Loses, Goals For, Goals Against, Goals Difference and Team Points in the group standing table. So my question: what is counted prior? At least I know team point is counted (compared) first. But if points are equal then on what basis the group standing is decided?

Related: [Qualification decision in group stages when everything is equal](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/916/540)

Comment: possible duplicate of [FIFA World Cup 2014 Tie Breaker Rules](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4881/fifa-world-cup-2014-tie-breaker-rules)

Comment: Actually the question is not duplicate but I got my answer from that question itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qualification decision in group stages when everything is equal](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/916/qualification-decision-in-group-stages-when-everything-is-equal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As FIFA rules declare:

1. By comparing goal differences
2. Total Goals scored
3. Goal difference resulting from the group matches between the teams concerned
4. Greater number of goals scored in all group matches between the teams concerned
5. Drawing of lots by the FIFA organizing committee
   These rules are only in FIFA World Cup

See [here](http://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Download/competitions/Regulations/01/87/54/21/1875421_DOWNLOAD.pdf) for more details

Comment: The previous reference (now removed) is for UEFA, not FIFA, making it irrelevant to this answer.

Comment: @Nij, it was referencing to UEFA website, but the booklet was for FIFA World Cup.

Comment: @Nij The edit was completely inappropriate. The referenced booklet is am official FIFA document, it just happens to be hosted at the UEFA web site. It was completely accurate for the 2014 World Cup, when the question and answer were written. You could have added that the information is outdated, but its not *wrong*.

Answer (score 3):

The more up-to-date answer for the [FIFA World Cup 2018](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup#Tiebreakers) is:

> 1. Points obtained in all group matches;
>
>    Goal difference in
>      all group matches;
>
>    Number of goals scored in all group matches;
>
>    Points obtained in the matches played between the teams in
>      question;
>
>    Goal difference in the matches played between the teams
>      in question;
>
>    Number of goals scored in the matches played between
>      the teams in question;
>
>    Fair play points in all group matches (only
>      one of these deductions shall be applied to a player in a single
>      match):
>
>    1. First yellow card: minus 1 point;
>
>       Indirect red
>         card (second yellow card): minus 3 points;
>
>       Direct red card: minus
>         4 points;
>
>       Yellow card and direct red card: minus 5 points;
>
>    Drawing of lots by the FIFA Organising Committee.